# Difference between these two OOP scenarios?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, extends, late-static-binding

I am confused what the difference or the performance gain would be between these 2 scenario's. Why would one be chosen over the other?

**Parent class:**

```
class exampleB
{
    public function __construct($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        // Do something with the arguments.
    }
}
```

**Child class A**

```
class exampleA extends exampleB
{
    public function make($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        parent::__construct($arg1, $arg2);
    }
}
```

> Running the first example:

```
$exampleA = new exampleA();
$exampleA->make('arg1', 'arg2');
```

The second example would be:

**Child class A**

```
class exampleA extends exampleB
{
    public static function make($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        return new static($arg1, $arg2);
    }
}
```

> Running the second example:

```
exampleA::make('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Could somebody tell me the advantages and/or disadvantages between these 2 scenarios? The reason I have these example because I do not want to override the constructor of my parent class.

Comment: I wouldn't use either, `$exampleA = new exampleA('arg1', 'arg2');` is all you need as the constructor in `exambleB` will be called automatically as long as you don't overwrite it.

Comment: I don't want to override the existing constructor in my parent class that's why I came up with these solutions. Should have added that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do neither and use the constructor to initialize the object. The object *must* be in a valid state after construction.

> The reason I have these example because I do not want to override the constructor of my parent class.

Then simply just don't define the constructor in the child class.

```
class Parent {
    public function __construct() {
        echo 'parent ctor called';
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {}

new Child(); // echo's parent ctor called
```

Answer (score -1):

I would opt for the second example. Make() acts like a constructor and thus should be called like one, i.e. static.

In the first example you create two objects instead of one. This might create some confusion when other devs read / mantain your code.